# Is there any event in js / jquery before 'focus' is trigged when prev / next button is clicked in iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

iPhone behavior - a glance:
Selecting an input field or select button open iPhone's default option selecting window, in that we could see prev / next button along with the options. Clicking on next button will take us directly to the next input / select field options.

Now I want to know which event to use before "focus" is called? (touchstart works only when we touch not with navigating through prev / next button)

Which doesn't work:
1. "touchstart" - works fine when you touch (click) the select box but not when we navigate through prev / next button.
2. "focus" - This triggers after touchstart event. I'm looking for something similar to touchstart which doesn't work with prev / next button.

What I want to achieve:
 1. I want to disable other fields when user enters a specific select field option through prev / next button in iphone.
 2. Using in focus doesn't do it because the select option window gets displayed before it's called.
 3. Using 'touchstart' works but as said not when navigating through prev / next button.

Thanks.